# ClarifAI Python API : Passing image captured from Webcam, to API, without saving on hard drive

Tags: python, api, machine-learning, computer-vision, image-recognition

I am using `ClarifAI python API` to classify objects capture from my `Raspberry PI` camera. (the whole program runs on `python` on `raspberry PI`).

Now, the two ways in which this `[Python API]` could be used is:

```
1> passing the path of the image in hard drive as argument while calling API.
2> passing the URL of the image as argument while calling API.
```

Now, I want to directly pass the image captured by my Pi Camera, using `picamera library` to this `API`, and get the tags, without saving it on the hard drive. How can I do it?
What kind variable I should be using to store the image data and for passing it on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a few ways to go about it.

1) Use the [`capture` function in picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-to-a-file) to save the file, push the file to Clarifai's function `tag_images`, then delete the file from the drive

2) Post the captured image's bytes to the Imgur (or similar) API and push the resulting URL to Clarifai's `tag_image_urls` function

3) Use REST instead of the Clarifai Python library and push the image bytes to the [/tag endpoint](https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/tag#tag)